# new to python 3, facing connectionRefused error, while setting up muliple client server setup

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

connectionRefused error:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*strong text**
I am trying to send message from one client to another through server but facing the above issue while running client

here is my server :

```
import socket

def Main():
HOST= '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 30000
clients = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen()
c, addr = s.accept() 
print('connection established')
while True:
    data = data.recv(1024)
    if addr not in clients:
        clients.append(addr)
        print('connected:', clients)
    if not data:
        break
    else:
        if addr == ['127.0.0.1',5000]:
            data= data.decode('utf-8')
            data= data.upper()
            data = data.encode('utf-8')
            s.sendto(data,['127.0.0.1',55000])

s.close()

if __name__ == '__main()':
    Main()
```

here is my client1 code:

```
import socket

def Main():

    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 50000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    print('connection established')

    msg = input("->")

    while True:
        s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
        print('msg is sent '+str(msg))
        msg = input('->')

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

here is my client 2 code:
    import socket

```
def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 55000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    print('connection established')


    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf')
        print('the response :'+data)

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

also, please share any kind of useful resource of Python 3 so that i could learn network programming. I am absolutely novice in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is listening on port 30000 and you're connecting to 50000 and 55000.